Is it possible to match impedance "with lower parasitic capacitance", or is parasitic capacitance itself a part of impedance
Parasitic capacitance makes the signal rise and fall slower, so I want it be as small as possible, but when I try to adjust parameters in Altium Designer (e.g. trace gap of a differential pair) for a lower parasitic capacitance, it always shows me similar value (with build-in 2D solver)?

The characteristic impedance of a PCB track (or a length of cable) is dependent (in the main) on two parameters namely inductance and capacitance. The transmission of light across the universe (through free-space) also encounters an impedance and, this also depends on the same two parameters (inductance per metre and capacitance per metre).
These two parameters define impedance and speed.

when I try to adjust parameters in Altium Designer (e.g trace gap of a
differential pair) for a lower parasitic capacitance, it always shows
me similar value

If you change the capacitance (whilst keeping the same characteristic impedance) you will change the inductance proportionately. This is because the lossless characteristic impedance is \$\sqrt{L/C}\$ hence, a change to both will not change the impedance.

is parasitic capacitance itself a part of impedance

Yes, it's part of the characteristic impedance, \$Z_0\$

Trace impedance depends on frequency, electrical length, and characteristic impedance.
At low frequencies (wavelength >> electrical length), we can reduce the impedance to a series inductance and shunt capacitance.  These are generally spoken of as strays, and the lumped equivalent works for most circuits -- as most circuits are built on PCBs were traces more than some inches length are rare, and most circuits rarely use [fundamental] frequencies over some 100s of MHz, 10s even.
At higher frequencies, particularly for high-speed digital communications (probably the most common case people will encounter when assembling new gadgets these days), harmonics must be included in that consideration (otherwise signal quality degrades), and indeed the fundamental itself may be included (it's not hard to attach e.g. PCIe devices to a modern SoC or SoM, using some Gbps at a minimum).  In this regime, transmission line parameters cannot be ignored, and electrical length and impedance matter.
Simply put: when using the transmission line as a transmission line, transmission line rules apply.  As long as adequate source and/or load termination is present, transmitters and receivers are placed along the bus according to their spec, and the receivers are designed to handle whatever signal they receive in specified positions, then it's fine.
Now, adjusting diff pair spacing, has a minor impact on Zo_diff, and no [instant] impact upon the bandwidth of the pair itself -- assuming it's driven/terminated by matching resistance, that is.  It does not impact rise/fall time, which is still dominated by lumped equivalents -- pin capacitance for example, or for a more sneaky intermediate case, stub length (can include via rings, unused via stubs, pin/pad geometry, etc., but also any stub traces of electrical length comparable to edge rate).
Now, varying Zo of a normal-mode trace, when used with source-terminated CMOS signaling, without also varying Rs, will result in apparent overshoot or slowdown; or for the limiting case Rs ≫ Zo, at low bit rates, the risetime will vary proportionally with C, which varies with Zo.  But as you can see, these are two very different situations, and they are treated differently as well.
Things are more complicated for RF, where the exact impedance matters a lot more, whether in terms of tuning and matching (narrow band), or flatness and phase linearity (wide band), but it is less common that people will be getting involved in that so I will not go into further detail.
It may be worth noting that digital comms are a subset of the RF wide band case, which has been chosen to be particularly easy to use (match impedances, observe diff pair balance, etc.).  Not that signal quality is the easiest thing ever, but relatively speaking.
